# How can I show the contents of each .txt file in a folder and their file name in the console?

Tags: c#

Basically, I want the command line to look like this:

```
filename1.txt
This is filename1.txt's contents
if possible add in another string here
filename2.txt
This is filename2.txt's contents
```

etc.

My current code logs this to the console:

```
This is filename1.txt's contents
This is filename2.txt's contents
This is filename3.txt's contents
```

etc.

My current code:

```cs
string objPath = "plugins/Stats/" + p.truename + "/objectives/";
if (!Directory.Exists(objPath)) {
    Console.Writeline("You have no objectives.");
}

else {
    int fCount = Directory.GetFiles(objPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;

    if (fCount == 0) {
        Console.Writeline("You have no objectives.");
    }

    else {
        foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(objPath, "*.txt")) {
            string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
            Console.Writeline(contents);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```
Console.Writeline(file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1));
```

before `Console.Writeline(contents);`

Answer (score 2):

[GetFileName()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=netframework-4.8) will give the name of the file.

```
Console.Writeline(Path.GetFileName(file));
```